# Extract JSON key from text file and then to create HTTP request

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a specific key (URL address) from a JSON result that is stored in text file (tweets.txt) and then to create HTTP GET request with the extracted URL address, the HTTP response should be saved as a new HTML file in the directory. The string I'm trying to extract is the value of specific JSON value.

For example:
"display_url":"test.com" (extract "test.com"  and then to create http request)

My code:

```
import json
import requests
with open('tweets.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        tweet_json = json.loads(line)
        response = requests.get(tweet_json.get('display_url')) if 'display_url' in tweet_json else {}
        if response and response.status_code()==200:
            print(response.html)
```

tweets.txt content:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Nov 15 11:35:00 +0000 2018","id":15292802,"id_str":325802","text":"test8  https:\/\/t.co\/ZtCsuk7Ek2   #osining","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":961508561217052675,"id_str":"961508561217052675","name":"Online S","screen_name":"osectraining","location":"Israel","url":"https:\/\/www.test.co.il","description":"test","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2,"friends_count":51,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":7,"created_at":"Thu Feb 08 07:54:39 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/961508561217052675\/1518076913","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"osectraining","indices":[33,46]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/ZtCsuk7Ek2","expanded_url":"http:\/\/test.com","display_url":"test.com","indices":[7,30]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1542281700508"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem is in the `json.loads` of specific line. do `json.loads` on `open('tweets.txt').read()` and then check if there is a `display_url` , if so - make a request with the `tweet_json.get('display_url')`

```
def send_req():
    import json
    import requests
    f = open('tweets.txt')
    tweet_json = json.loads(f.read())
    response = requests.get(tweet_json.get('display_url',None))
    if response and response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.html)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and just call this function while the return value of this function is `True`

```
import time
while not send_req():
    time.sleep(60) # seconds
```

Comment: But this is a file that gets new data every few minutes. So I must always read the new data that is received.

Comment: so you will need to read the whole file each time and not each line'

Comment: Can you post an example ?

Comment: File "request2.py", line 7
    if response and response.status_code()==200:
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Same error:   if response and response.status_code == 200:
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: copy my entire answer and test it . i know you did it but i forgot an `)` at the end of the `requests.get`

Comment: ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 2474 - 4955)

Comment: where is that problem ?? please copy all ! the error !

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request2.py", line 14, in <module>
    while not send_req():
  File "request2.py", line 5, in send_req
    tweet_json = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 2474 - 4955)

Comment: your tweets.txt is not valid JSON file !